# C# OpenFileDialog not opening file

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm trying to use openFileDialog to open a Bitmap image and place it on my form.  My form construtor...

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drawing = new Bitmap(drawingPanel.Width, drawingPanel.Height, drawingPanel.CreateGraphics());
        Graphics.FromImage(drawing).Clear(Color.White);

        // set default value for line thickness
        tbThickness.Text = "5";
    }
```

... opens a new form with a blank screen, and I can draw on it using the mouse and various color selector buttons.  I then save the file with this method:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // save drawing
        if (file == null)   // file is a FileInfo object that I want to use
                            // to check to see if the file already exists 
                            // I haven't worked that out yet
        {
            drawing.Save("test.bmp");
            //SaveBitmap saveForm = new SaveBitmap();
            //saveForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            drawing.Save(fi.FullName);
        }
    }
```

The image does save to the debug folder as a .bmp file.  Then I use OpenFileDialog to open the file:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream myStream;
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = (FileStream)openFile.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
                        picBox.Location = drawingPanel.Location;
                        picBox.Size = drawingPanel.Size;
                        picBox.Image = new Bitmap(openFile.FileName);
                        this.Controls.Add(picBox);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

What happes is that OpenFileDialog box comes up.  When I select the file test.bmp, the screen goes away and then reappears, when I select it again, the OpenFileDialog window goes away and I'm back to my form with no image.  Was hoping for some pointers.  No compile or runtime errors.

Comment: What is drawingPanel?

Comment: You're talking about a lot of things at once. What is your main question? If you want to know why it pops up twice: Well, it's because you have two `OpenFileDialog`s, `dlg`, and `d`

Comment: Have you checked to see that the code inside the if statement is executed?

Comment: Now that I see that I was calling OpenDialog twice, and have fixed that, my main question is why the image isn't showing up on my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `ShowDialog()` twice?

Just call `ShowDialog` once, so it doesn't open *twice*, like you indicated.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx):

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            using (myStream)
            {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
                PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
                picBox.Location = drawingPanel.Location;
                picBox.Size = drawingPanel.Size;
                picBox.Image = new Bitmap (myStream);
                this.Controls.Add(picBox);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ryrich.  Like evanmcdonnal's answer, everything seems to function, but the image just never shows up on the form.

Comment: @deadEddie: try messing with the PictureBox options, maybe picBox.Visible = true and make sure Location and Size are being set correctly.

Comment: Everything seems okay, size and location are set correctly and visible is set to true.  On my form, I place a drawing panel (drawingPanel), which I use to locate and size my bitmap image.  I'm wondering if I should have used a picture box instead.

Comment: @deadEddie: I've tested this on my computer (just the OpenDialog portion), and I opened a sample bmp image and it works fine. The image pops up on my form. My Location and Size are different than your code, try changing those (maybe like `picBox.Location = new Point(0,0)` and `picBox.Size = new Size(100,100)` just as a test?)

Comment: That was very helpful.  The problem I seem to be having is that the image will display anywhere on the form EXCEPT for the area where I want the picture box !?  Do you think my constructor (see above) would impact that?

Comment: thanks for your help -- got it going.  What was going on is that the canvas I created in my constructor was "hiding" the new PictureBox image.  I dealt with it by using the same PictureBox and Bitmap objects.  Really appreciate your help throughout!

Answer (score 0):

You open a dialog panel, then when it closes you check to see if the result was OK; then you open another new dialog in the `using` block; then you assign the image result of that to the `PictureBox`, and then throw everything away when the `using` block disposes.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `ShowDialogue` twice which is likely the source of your problem. Just use the following code, remove everything else from the method. Your use of `using` is also incorrect. it does clean up which is disposing of the results. You need to refactor or remove the using statement.

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog()
     {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
                picBox.Location = drawingPanel.Location;
                picBox.Size = drawingPanel.Size;
                picBox.Image = new Bitmap (dlg.FileName);
                this.Controls.Add(picBox);
            }
      }
  }
```

The code above works but is without clean up or error handling. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Too many brackets, but the code runs, with the exception that no image is showing up on my form.

Comment: @deadEddie I don't know much about `PictureBox` but try, `picBox.ImageLocation = dlg.FileName;` `BitMap` inherits from Image so I think it should work but I would inspect the Bitmap to make sure that object is correctly constructed, if it is add a cast `(Image)` or try setting the `ImageLocation` property instead.

Comment: I tried picBox.ImageLocation = dlg.FileName.  Everything seems to work, I'm just not getting the image to show up on the form :(

Comment: @deadEddie what is the value of `picBox.visible` ? The problem is likely outside of this block of code.

Comment: the value of picBox.Visible is true